# Are there any hooks that get called before modules are loaded?

Tags: 7, hooks

There are a few user tracking checks I would like to perform before the site main page gets loaded. I don't really want to have to wait for drupal to load all the modules and start running the theme code before I do this.

Are there any hooks that can be overwritten to perform my checks?

Comment: hook_init()/hook_boot()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend using [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) as it doesn't run on cached pages. Try using [hook_boot()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7). As per the documentation it runs at the beginning of the page request when Drupal is still in the bootstrap. Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, This does answer my question, but I now realize... how do I use this hook? If no modules are loaded at this point, where should I overwrite this hook? the docs don't seem to give answers to these questions as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Onema hook_init() must be implemented in a custom module. The function mymodule_init() would go into a file named mymodule.module in a custom module named mymodule. You would also supply a simple mymodule.info file and put both files in the sites/sitename/modules/mymodule directory.

The custom module must be enabled like any other. Also, when creating a hook implementation, it is usually necessary to clear the cache for Drupal to recognize it. Finally, note that mymodule needs to be a unique name different from other modules or themes.

Comment: hook_init() and hook_boot() are obviously executed *after* the modules have been loaded, a hook is by definition something that can be implemented by a module. You can't invoke a hook before the modules are loaded. Also note that if you want to track *authenticated users*, then hook_init() is the recommended way to do so, pages aren't cached for them anyway.

Comment: @Berdir: I think you could post it as a separate answer, your comment was really helpful. Not to mention that in fact it IS an answer to the original question, too. :) hanleyhansen: +1, your post was useful too.